# Python scroll textbox

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am having trouble implementing a textbox with a scroll on the side(image below).
The following code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
[enter image description here][1]
text1 = Text(root, wrap=WORD, height=10, width=50)
y_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(orient=VERTICAL, command=text1.yview)
text1['yscrollcommand'] = y_scrollbar.set

y_scrollbar.grid(root, row=0, column=1)
text1.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I keep getting an error at y_scrollbar.grid(root, row=0, column=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `.grid()` incorrectly. You should change this `y_scrollbar.grid(root, row=0, column=1)`  to `y_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1)`. No need to include root.